# How is a file split / chunked? How do I access the chunks sequentially?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I have an image and I download it -- how does the computer know that all the bytes are supposed to be in that sequential order?

When I upload an image, is it possible to upload it in "chunks" so I can access/use whatever I have uploaded thus far (i.e. I have only uploaded the top half of the image) -- how would I access it?

The same would go for video or PDF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file into chunks and upload file in chunks.

See the example below.

```
<input type="file" name="filebrowsefileid">
```

---

```
var filePicker = document.getElementById('filebrowsefileid'); 

var file = filePicker.files[0];
var chunck = file.slice(a,b);
var reader  = new FileReader();

 reader.readAsBinaryString(chunck );
```

....

```
 reader["onloadend"] = function () {
   reader.result; // This is what you want 
}
```